# How to Change the Opportunity Amount

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

Once I add Products to the Opportunity I can no longer edit the Opportunity's Amount field.  Is it possible to change that amount so that it is saved on the Opportunity as a different amount? Possibly with workflow or a trigger?  I tried a workflow and it looked like it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [help](https://na9.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/opp_fields.htm):

> For opportunities with products, the amount is the sum of the related products. You cannot directly edit the amount unless the opportunity has no products. To change the amount for an opportunity that contains products, edit the sales price or quantity of the related products.

Comment: Does that mean you can't do it directly through the UI or altogether, including apex, etc?  I see it is locked down through the UI.

Comment: If it's locked even for SysAdmin I wouldn't have high hopes ;)

Comment: It is not possible through apex or the api. If you try and change it through apex you will not get a dmlexception. It just silently fails to change it.

Comment: Thanks! I see that too.  Interesting to fail silently.  I wonder if there's some performance reason for locking it down after products have been added.  I understand that 95% of the time it would probably be a misuse to do this, but if there aren't any performance reasons, I would've thought SF would let it happen.